# Specifications of Bell's inequality experiments conducted untill now

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality, epr-experiment

Has any Bell's inequality experiment, conducted until now, which has satisfied the following criteria?

1. Having more than three measuring orientations. In the typical experimental setup I have seen online, it always has three directions while measuring the spin of electron like 0, 120 and 240 degrees or 0, 45 and 90 degrees. Does any of the experiments use more than three orientations, like 0, 72, 144, 216 and 288 degrees?

Image Source: [Quantum Entanglement & Spooky Action at a Distance by Vertasium](https://youtu.be/ZuvK-od647c)

[image]

2. Were all the measurements of the experiment made within a period which light takes to travel between the two measuring locations. Let's say the two locations are one light second apart, and there were 100 set of electron entangled pairs were tested, was the first pair of entangled particles and the last pair of entangled particles tested with in a span of 1 second, I mean were 200 measurements, both side included done within 1 second.
   **Note** I'm not asking the time between measurement of entangled particles, I'm asking for time span of the measurement of the entire experiment

**OR**

3. Was the apparatus stopped and restarted and messed with before each consecutive measurement?

I'm only trying to see if the possibility of any latent and delayed communication between entanglement making machine and the orientation testing machines, so that some state transfer of possible measuring directions can be communicated which can still break Bell's inequality while maintaining localism.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this question can be answered without referring to a specific  experimental paper (or to a set of specific papers). You might want to read a recent literature review. Among the APS physics journals, *Annual Reviews* is good for research-level details, while *American Journal of Physics* tends to be pitched at educators and might be a gentler introduction.

Comment: @rob Thanks. That is why I am asking about the latest and most state of the art experiment. Also I think we normal people do not have access to research papers.

Comment: There won’t be a single such experiment. Every experiment has tradeoffs, and is more sensitive to some things at the expense of other things. Many research papers are submitted pre-publication to [arXiv](https://arxiv.org) and can be accessed there at no cost. If it’s easier to search for authors (or for talks by an author), there’s a lot of good work from Zeilinger and his group at Vienna.

Comment: @rob will edity question accordingly

Comment: Why is your second point important here? I would say that what is important is the spacetime separation for each measurement, not the total runtime. Anyway, the term you should be looking for is 'loophole-free Bell tests'.

Comment: @KennethGoodenough my second point is very very important. We have already verifed the time separation of individual measurements. But there could still be communication between devices where a past measurement influences the future measurements. Where not the particles but devices communicate and with each other using particles. So total runtime is important or third point where devices are disturbed and experiment is not continous.

Comment: There is no way to ensure that past measurements will not influence future measurements. An obvious example would be superdeterminism, which one cannot rule out without making any further assumptions.

Comment: To add, there are ways to make *less likely* that the random numbers used for the measurements are correlated, however. I forgot the research group, but one of the first loophole-free experiments XOR'ed the data generated from their RNG with the Lord of the Ring movies (and others). For a paper I helped out with, we XOR'ed the RNG output with tweets from Justin Bieber and One Direction fans.

Comment: @KennethGoodenough the data and future influence is not stored or influenced by the random numbers you use. You can use amy random numbers. I have a model where a local deterministic system will break the Bell's inequality if past measurements can influence future measurements and there's only three measuring directions.